# Access spline direction to instance points aligned to simple poly spline

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to create a setup that takes:

- a curve with x amount of splines

and instances an object on

- **each** 1st point of **each** spline
- pointing into the **direction of the spline** (simple straight alignment will suffice, no bending needed)
- scaled so it is as long as the spline itself

the first points of each spline I can select using the "Endpoint Selection" node

**The direction I am conceptually, trying to capture by substracting the position of the point at index 1 + 1 from the position of the point at index 1, feeding it into a Euler to Vector. This I can't get to work.**

Scaling, I haven't thought about as much. I think I need to get the spline length and multiply it by the dimensions of the instance to get the scaling in some way.

So, how would I get a vector pointing between the first and second point on EACH spline, and have the instances be aligned to that vector for each individual first point.

Answer (score 0):

This setup generates some random splines then positions a tetrahedron on each 1st point, with nominal height of 1, but scaled to the length of the spline:

[image]

zooming in on the actual solution:

[image]

[image]